# How do I add a class dynamically when using .NET

Tags: .net, reserved-words

I have a top nav and I'm in a .NET framework. I want to check the value of a variable and add an active class if need be. I'm not a .NET guy, so I'm scratching my head over this since I have:

```
<li @if(ViewBag.Area == "account"){ class="active"}><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
```

But, as I'm sure all you .NET folks are nodding about right now, that doesn't work since `class` is reserved.

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<li @if(ViewBag.Area == "account"){ <text>class="active"</text>}>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark it as the answer as soon as SO lets me.